# Importing BACPAC via SSMS to Azure SQL Server fails with AzureAD user

Tags: sql-server, azure, entra-id, ssms

Recently, trying to import a BACPAC to an Azure SQL Server using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) has been failing with the following error:

[image]

> Failed to connect to server ___.database.windows.net.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

---

The steps I have used to import the BACPAC are as follows:

1. Connect to server in SSMS using my AzureAD credentials.
2. Right click on Databases and choose "Import Data-tier application"
3. Select my BACPAC file and click next.
4. Leave default settings for S2 Azure DB and click next.
5. Error appears before it gets to the Summary page.

---

The above steps have worked great for the last 2 years, and just recently stopped working. I've tried on 2 different computers, different networks, and different versions of SSMS (that have worked find in the past) but they all still fail.

Using a regular SQL server password login (non AzureAD account) imports the BACPAC successfully, as does importing via Azure Portal.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462674/sql-server-returns-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon) ?